# Does Munitions Crafter stack with the Alchemist Dedication?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, alchemist, gunslinger

Both the [Alchemist Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=665) and [Munitions Crafter](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3158) grant me infused reagents equal to my level. Do they stack if I take both, gaining reagents equal to twice my level per day? This seems wrong, giving a Gunslinger the potential to have more reagents than an equivalently leveled Alchemist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### [Alchemical Archetypes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1435) Don't Stack

> If you gain infused reagents from more than one source, you use the highest number of reagents to determine your pool rather than adding them together.

Comment: ahh, I didn't expect those to be in the APG. Good spot, thanks!